# Django Stopping loop after x times within a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have queryset that returns many records but in the template I use it twice to return value.

For example:
On one instance I need to return the latest 5 posts and then show all the posts on that same page. So for that reason I can't use LIMIT in my queryset.

```
{% for post in blog_posts %}
<li>{{ post.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

From that example how can I stop to loop after 5 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `slice` filter:

```
{% for post in blog_posts|slice:":5" %}
<li>{{ post.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```